# How to exclude modules from google play services library?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-play-services, project-structure

I'm working with an Android app and I'm trying to exclude modules from gms because I exceeded the limit of methods that can be referenced:

> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split) shows an example using gradle, but the project I'm working on doesn't use gradle. Is there other way to do that? I'm using intellij idea 14, and the dependencies are configured manually using *Project Structure* window.

I'm trying with *Project Structure -> Libraries -> Exclude* and then I select the library modules I don't need, but it's not working apparently. I'm not sure if that's the right way

Also tried *File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Excludes*. But seems like I can only exclude the whole library.

Comment: What does it use instead of gradle?

Comment: the project uses ant

Answer (score 0):

You need to include only the required things for your app from the  play services lib as shown below,

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
}
```

Here I have added only gcm from the entire set of play services like that use only what is required.

Since play services include everything from wallet, ads, location etc it easily cruises the dex limit, even after doing so if you get the error try doing mutidex=true seeing in your file

Comment: your answer is for Gradle, but he said that he's not using Gradle in his project.